# PHP Non direct assignment by reference

Tags: php, reference

PHP 7.0

<del>I note really strange behavior with assignment of arrays. Arrays in PHP should be assigned by value copy (if not directly set to reference).</del>

Variable referenced once in local scope become referenced everywhere (That is what I guess). In my opinion this is not how it should work. I want to create reference in one place but copy value in other.

Please take look at this example

```
class A
{

    public $b;

    public $refVar;

    public function __construct(B $b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;

        // reference here
        $this->refVar = &$this->b->vars['randoms'];
    }

}

class B
{

    public $vars = [];
    public $history = [];


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->vars['randoms'] = [];
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // copy value here
        $this->history[] = $this->vars;

        $this->vars['randoms'][] = rand();
    }

}

$b = new B();

echo "After B::__construct\n";
var_dump($b->vars);

$a = new A($b);

echo "\n\nAfter A::__construct(B)\n";
var_dump($b->vars);

$b->doSomething();

echo "\n\nAfter B::doSomething()\n";
var_dump($b->vars);

$b->doSomething();
$b->doSomething();

echo "\n\nB::history\n";
var_dump($b->history);
```

**Result**

```
After B::__construct
array(1) {
  ["randoms"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}


After A::__construct(B)
array(1) {
  ["randoms"]=>
  &array(0) {
  }
}


After B::doSomething()
array(1) {
  ["randoms"]=>
  &array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(85799664)
  }
}


B::history
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["randoms"]=>
    &array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(85799664)
      [1]=>
      int(418164754)
      [2]=>
      int(1267239969)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["randoms"]=>
    &array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(85799664)
      [1]=>
      int(418164754)
      [2]=>
      int(1267239969)
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["randoms"]=>
    &array(3) {
      [0]=>
      int(85799664)
      [1]=>
      int(418164754)
      [2]=>
      int(1267239969)
    }
  }
}
```

[code fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8e101869afac77e92fc214e1d3cc12d5e35966f)

As you can see making reference to B::vars in A::__construct scope makes B::vars referenced everywhere.

How to prevent this?

**EDIT:** After long research I simplified example. And found what is wrong - however I dont know how to prevent this situation.

Meta: No one answered yet so I changed a little question. I don't want to close it because someone already followed it.

**EDIT 2** I have posted my solution that is not fully satisfying. 
If someone has any idea how to overcome this (maybe by changing concept) any suggestions are welcome. But keep in mind that reference to B::vars in A class is required as well as possibility to save states of that variable.

Comment: When you use `&` in the variable, you are assigning a reference to it. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.php

Comment: Note that reference is used in A constructor not in B::pushState()

Comment: There is ugly solution: unserialize(serialize(...)) however in my opinion there should be some more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been already mention as a [bug on php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=20993)

It seems that only solution is to use serialize or json_encode - which will have large impact on performance.